# Create box template jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, clone

I am having some tempate that i want to add and remove with jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="row box template">
    <label class="input box" for="foldername">
        <span class="icon-prepend input-index-number">1.1.1</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-folder-name" placeholder="Please article" />
        <button class="btn btn-no-borders button-remove" type="button">
            <i class="icon-delete-input"></i>
        </button>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="row box">
    <label class="input" for="foldername">
        <span class="icon-prepend input-index-number">1.1.1</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-folder-name" placeholder="Please enter article" />

    </label>
</div>

   <div class="row">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-add">Add article</button>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.template{
  display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-add", function () {
    $('.box.template').clone()
        .show()
        .removeClass("template")
        .insertAfter(".box:last");
});
$(document).on("click", ".button-remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("row").remove();
});
```

When i click on add i want to add new filed with inout, but when i click on delete to remove just that field

Please check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9490/

You will see what i need, the problem is here it always add new row, and that why mu layout break

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please check fiddle, you will see how its showing

Comment: Check the html structure where you add the template I think its added at the wrong place. Must it not be added outside the row box div?

Comment: Questions should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go to external site to figure out what the top level problem is. Explain it in your question. Rememebr that interpretations may differ when a clear problem isn't defined

Comment: Please can you check fiddle, you will see what is problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there was something wrong with select `('.box:last')` and that's the
  main problem so I changed it to `insertBefore('.row:last')` and it works
  will
- in `closest('row')` you should add dot to define your class so I
  changed it to `closest('.row')`

  ```
  $(document).on("click", ".button-add", function () {
       var lastbox = $('.box').length;
      alert(lastbox);
      $('.template').clone()
          .show()
          .removeClass("template")
          .insertBefore('.row:last');
  }).on("click", ".button-remove", function () {
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  });
  ```

  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9495/)